# Ninject: Controller Constructor with int argument

Tags: ninject

How can you instantiate a Controller that has an int argument?
Using Ninject..

My HomeController has a constructor like this:

```
  private int _masterId;
  Public HomeController(int masterId){
       _masterId = masterId;
}
```

I created a controller factory like this:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new ExampleConfigModule());

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
        {

            return controllerType == null ? null
                                          : (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType, 1);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work with Ninject 1.0, but does work with 2.0

```
var controller = kernel.Get<IController>(new ConstructorArgument("masterId", 1));
```

However it's probably not too good idea to pass arguments to constructor manually when using IoC container.